# Default text tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a password generator in python and I want to leave default text in the "Password" area. I know this question has been asked before but those examples did not help me.

```
import random 
import pyperclip 
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# Function for calculation of password 
def low(): 
    entry.delete(0, END) 
  
    # Get the length of passowrd 
    length = var1.get() 
  
    lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    digits = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*"
    password = "" 
  
    # if strength selected is low 
    if var.get() == 1: 
        for i in range(0, length): 
            password = password + random.choice(lower) 
        return password 
  
    # if strength selected is medium 
    elif var.get() == 0: 
        for i in range(0, length): 
            password = password + random.choice(upper) 
        return password 
  
    # if strength selected is strong 
    elif var.get() == 3: 
        for i in range(0, length): 
            password = password + random.choice(digits) 
        return password 
    else: 
        print("Please choose an option") 
  
  
# Function for generation of password 
def generate(): 
    password1 = low() 
    entry.insert(10, password1) 

#Discord Invite 
def discord_inv():
    webbrowser.open_new("https://discord.gg/VRccYxe")
  
  
# Function for copying password to clipboard 
def copy1(): 
    random_password = entry.get() 
    pyperclip.copy(random_password) 
  

# Main Function 
  
# create GUI window 
root = Tk() 
root.geometry("415x60")
# root['bg'] = '#2a2f38'
var = IntVar() 
var1 = IntVar() 
  
# Discord Image
img = Image.open('discord.png')
img = img.resize((25, 25), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

# Title of your GUI window 
root.title("Corduroys Password Generator") 
  
# create label and entry to show 
# password generated 
Random_password = Label(root, text="Password") 
Random_password.grid(row=0) 
entry = Entry(root) 
entry.grid(row=0, column=1) 
  
# create label for length of password 
c_label = Label(root, text="Length") 
c_label.grid(row=1) 
  
# create Buttons Copy which will copy (duh)
# password to clipboard and Generate 
# which will generate the password 
copy_button = Button(root, text="Copy", command=copy1) 
copy_button.grid(row=0, column=2) 
generate_button = Button(root, text="Generate", command=generate) 
generate_button.grid(row=0, column=3) 
discord_botton = Button(root, text="Click", image=img, command=discord_inv)
discord_botton.grid(row=0, column=4)
  
# Radio Buttons for deciding the 
# strength of password 
# Default strength is Medium 
radio_low = Radiobutton(root, text="Low", variable=var, value=1) 
radio_low.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='E') 
radio_middle = Radiobutton(root, text="Medium", variable=var, value=0) 
radio_middle.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky='E') 
radio_strong = Radiobutton(root, text="Strong", variable=var, value=3) 
radio_strong.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky='E') 
combo = Combobox(root, textvariable=var1)  
  
# Combo Box for length of your password 
combo['values'] = (8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
                   17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
                   26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32) 
combo.current(0) 
combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>') 
combo.grid(column=1, row=1) 
  
# start the GUI 
root.mainloop()
```

[The current app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqUGg.png)

*A bonus issue to be solved is resizing the discord logo so its the same size as the rest of the buttons but the actually image stays the same size.*

Comment: What didn't they help? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. An example with a password with default text shouldn't take more than five or six lines. We don't need 100 lines of code.

Comment: how about `entry.insert("end", "Default Text")`

Comment: maybe logo has to be smaller then `25x25` to fit to other elements.

Comment: Is calling `generate()` before `root.mainloop()` what you need?

Comment: @furas The problem with that is that then the image is stretched.

Comment: maybe you have to crop image - remove background around logo using any image editor - and then it will fit to other elements.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways you can set values for text entry widgets by using `tkinter.StringVar()`

```py
string_var = tkinter.StringVar(root)
entry_widget = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=string_var)
string_var.set(value="Default Text")
```

Comment: You don't have to use a `StringVar`. The `Entry` widget has methods for inserting and extracting text.

Comment: Yes but that would require deleting existing text then entering new text. It’s not necessary, but it is much easier to use.

Comment: Sure, two lines of code instead of one, but in exchange for having a separate object that has to be managed. My point is, your answer makes it sound like using a `StringVar` is the only solution rather than just _a_ solution.

Comment: I don't understand how my answer makes it sound like `StringVar` is the only solution. I said that 'you can', not 'you must'. Both the `insert` method and `StringVar` objects are the practical solution in different scenarios, and I feel that `StringVar` is more appropriate here, which is why my answer uses `StringVar`.

Comment: It's because you say "you can do X with Y" instead of "one of the ways you can do X is Y" or "there are two ways to do X: with Y or with Z".

Comment: I guess I can see that, so, in that case, I edited my answer according to your suggestion.